# when i hit the run button The message is that TypeError: Student() takes no arguments

Tags: python-3.x

Please find blow code snippet.

```
class Student:

def _init_(self, name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
    self.name = name
    self.major = major
    self.gpa = gpa
    self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation



from Student import Student

student1 = Student("Jim", "Business", 3.1, False)

print(student1.gpa)
```

So when i hit the run button saying that:

> TypeError: Student() takes no arguments

Answer (score 2):

The init function is not `_init_` but `__init__`

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa, is_on_probation):
        self.name = name
        self.major = major
        self.gpa = gpa
        self.is_on_probation = is_on_probation

student1 = Student("Jim", "Business", 3.1, False)
print(student1.gpa)
```

Comment: Hahaha... you won by time..just 13 seconds

Comment: just going to upvote your answer and delete my answer